# How can I change the color of a rectangle?

Tags: javafx

Where am i going wrong with my logic to simply change the color of the rectangle when clicked?

```
        square.setFill(null);
        square.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        getChildren().addAll(square);

        setOnMouseClicked(event ->{
            if(event.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {              
                square.setFill(Color.BLUE);
            }
            else if(square.getFill().equals(Color.BLUE)) {
                    square.setFill(Color.BLACK);
            }


        });
```

Comment: What happens if you step through the setOnMouseClicked, does it flow through the 2 different paths as expected?

Comment: When I click on the square it turns it straight black, skipping the turn blue code

Comment: What object are you calling `setOnMouseClicked` on? You don't appear to be calling it on the `square`; looks like you're calling it on `this`.

Comment: Are you even left-clicking?

Answer (score 1):

I think you dont require a boolean flag. What you are doing can be done as below:

```
setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
    if (event.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {
       square.setFill(square.getFill() == Color.BLUE ? Color.BLACK : Color.BLUE);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a boolean to flag if the rectangle is blue or not.

```
        square.setFill(null);
        square.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        getChildren().addAll(square);

        setOnMouseClicked(event ->{
            if(event.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {              
                if(!isBlue) {
                    square.setFill(Color.BLUE);
                    isBlue = true;
                }
                else if(isBlue) {

                    square.setFill(Color.BLACK);
                    isBlue = false;
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you might find with using a variable is that you have to have a variable which you track for each object that you want to support changing color on or your objects that change color will all be triggered on the same variable.

I think you can keep your original code, I think the issue is your if statement:

```
setOnMouseClicked(event ->{
    if(event.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {              
        square.setFill(Color.BLUE);
    }
    else if(square.getFill().equals(Color.BLUE)) {
            square.setFill(Color.BLACK);
    }
```

If you look at it, the condition is if the getButton is the Primary and if true, it will always set it to blue and if the user didn't use the primary button, it will only set to black if the color is blue.

You want something like:

```
setOnMouseClicked(event ->{
    if(event.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {              
       if(!square.getFill().equals(Color.BLUE)) {
           square.setFill(Color.BLUE);
       }
       else
               square.setFill(Color.BLACK);
       }
   }
}
```